# PHP Custom Session Handler Problems (PHP 7.1)

Tags: php, session

I've just migrated from PHP 7.0 to PHP 7.1 (fresh/clean install of the current version of WAMP) on a computer and it seems to have broken something in the custom session handler that's supposed to save the session to the database instead of using the file system.

The custom hander class is:

```php
class db_session_handler implements SessionHandlerInterface {

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function open($save_path,$session_name) {
        $this->db;
        return true;
    }

    public function close() {
        unset($this->db);
        return true;
    }

    public function read($session_id) {

        if (!isset($session_id)) {
            $session_id='';
        }

        try {
            $sql="
                SELECT
                    sess_data
                FROM
                    ue_user_session
                WHERE
                    sess_id = :sess_id
            ";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sess_id', $session_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if (count($res) <> 1 ) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return $res[0]['sess_data'];
            }
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('Error reading the session data table in the session reading method.',3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
            error_log(" Query with error: $sql",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
            error_log(" Reason given: $e->getMessage()",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function write($session_id,$session_data) {

        try {
            $sql="
                SELECT
                    sess_data
                FROM
                    ue_user_session
                WHERE
                    sess_id = :sess_id
            ";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sess_id', $session_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('Error reading the session data table in the session reading method.',3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
            error_log(" Query with error: $sql",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
            error_log(" Reason given: $e->getMessage()",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
            return false;
        }
        $ip = get_ip();
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            $user_id = (int) $_SESSION['user_id'];
        } else {
            $user_id= (int) 0;
        }       
        if (empty($res)) {

            if (!isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'])) {
                $location = 'Unknown';
            } else {
                $location = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
            }

            try {
                if (count($res) === 0) {
                    $sql="
                        INSERT INTO
                            ue_user_session
                        (
                              sess_id
                            , user
                            , start
                            , last_activity
                            , location
                            , ip
                            , user_agent
                            , user_host
                            , user_language
                            , expires
                            , sess_data
                        )
                        VALUES
                            (
                                  :sess_id
                                , 0
                                , NOW()
                                , NOW()
                                , :location
                                , :ip
                                , :user_agent
                                , :user_host
                                , :user_lang
                                , DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
                                , :sess_data                        
                            )               
                    ";

                    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':sess_id', $session_id);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':location', $location);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':user_agent', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':user_host', $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':user_lang', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':sess_data', $session_data);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                error_log('Error reading the session data table in the session reading method.',3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
                error_log(" Query with error: $sql",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
                error_log(" Reason given: $e->getMessage()",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
                return false;
            }
        } else {

            try {
                $sql="
                    UPDATE
                        ue_user
                    SET
                        last_activity = NOW()
                    WHERE
                        id =  :user_id
                ";
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                error_log('Error reading the session data table in the session reading method.',3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
                error_log(" Query with error: $sql",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
                error_log(" Reason given: $e->getMessage()",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
                return false;
            }


            if (!isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'])) {
                $location = 'Unknown';
            } else {
                $location = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
            }
            try {

                $sql="
                    UPDATE
                        ue_user_session
                    SET
                          last_activity = NOW()
                        , expires = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
                        , location = :location
                        , ip = :ip
                        , user_agent = :user_agent
                        , user_host = :user_host
                        , user_language = :user_lang
                        , sess_data = :sess_data
                        , user = :user_id
                    WHERE
                        sess_id = :sess_id              
                ";

                $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':location', $location);
                $stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
                $stmt->bindParam(':user_agent', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':user_host', $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':user_lang', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':sess_data', $session_data);
                $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
                $stmt->bindParam(':sess_id', $session_id);
                $stmt->execute();
                return true;
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                error_log('Error reading the session data table in the session reading method.',3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
                error_log(" Query with error: $sql",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
                error_log(" Reason given: $e->getMessage()",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
                return false;
            }
        }
        $this->gc();
    }

    public function destroy($session_id) {
        try {
            $sql="
                DELETE FROM
                    ue_user_session
                WHERE
                    sess_id = :sess_id
            ";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sess_id', $session_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('Error reading the session data table in the session reading method.',3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
            error_log(" Query with error: $sql",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
            error_log(" Reason given: $e->getMessage()",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function gc($max_lifetime) {
        try {
            $sql="
                DELETE FROM
                    ue_user_session
                WHERE
                    NOW() > expires
            ";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('Error reading the session data table in the session reading method.',3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
            error_log(" Query with error: $sql",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
            error_log(" Reason given: $e->getMessage()",3,"C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\test_log.txt");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It's initilised by:

```php
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

$db_session_handler = new db_session_handler($db);
session_set_save_handler($db_session_handler, true);

if (session_start() === false ) {
    die('The Session Handler Is Broken!!!!');
}
```

Reading through the manual page for `session_set_save_handler()` I can't spot anything mentioned that might explain the error that I'm getting which is:

> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: c:/wamp/tmp) in C:\wamp\www\universal_empires\libs\bootstrap.php on line 36

Line 36 in that file is the call to `session_start()`.

Googling around the only fixes that I can find are specific to a given framework. What I need to know is what's causing `session_start()` to fail (from reading about changes to 7.1 `session_start()` returns false instead of trying to plod on when something's not right.

My guess is that something has changed in 7.1 where in 7.0 possibly it was allowed to carry on but in 7.1 it's more stricter with whatever the problem is and makes `session_start()` return false.

I've emptied the sessions table in the database and have checked where file-based sessions get stored. The only "file-based" session file present is PHPMyAdmin.

Does anyone know what it's falling foul of in PHP 7.1 that it doesn't fall foul of in PHP 7.0?

Comment: Very first thought reactions: what does session_set_save_handler return -- true or false? And did upgrading PHP change any php.ini values you need? I'm looking for other answers.

Comment: session_set_save_handler returns true. I had to do a fresh install of WAMP as the old install for some reason had crapped itself and deleted it's php.ini file

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Culprit has been found. It turns out that session_start() doesn't like the read method of a custom session handler returning false if there's no session in existence. if anyone else gets a similar problem, if you've no session in existence, then the read method needs to return an empty string instead of either false or null.

The solution was found at http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#120589 i was looking at the the manual page for session_set_save_handler(), not expecting the solution to actually be in the comments section of the session_start() page.

I don't know why the change was made to what the session_start() method expects to get from the read method of a custom session handler

Comment: Thanks for the solution - but is this some sort of bug in versions 7.1 / 7.2 ?

Comment: Don't think it's a bug, just where they've changed what session_start() expects to get when there's no existing session

Comment: This bug exists in PHP 8.2.0 RC4. Thanks for tracking that down.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst converting interspire shopping cart to php7.2 we had to add

`return $session='';`

to line 98 of class.sessions.php. That god rid of the warning.